# Limiting IPs during Azure Migrate

Tags: azure, ip-address, winrm, azure-migrate

I am preparing to use Azure Migrate and as noted in the prerequisites, I need to "allow inbound connections on WinRM port 5985 (HTTP) for discovery of Windows servers".

Can this opening be limited to a particular IP address or subnet?

I can open the port, but I would like to limit it to the intended Azure traffic.

Comment: Please refer this document- [specify which IP-addresses the WinRM service will listen on](https://support.vscope.net/how-to-enable-winrm-on-windows-servers-clients#:~:text=WinRM%20uses%20ports%205985%20%28HTTP,node%20and%20choose%20New%20Rule.)
and [MS QnA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1412233/limiting-ips-during-azure-migration)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to limit inbound traffic on WinRM port 5985 to a particular IP address or subnet, you can create a network security group on azure portal and select the specific IP address or subnet that you want to allow access to WinRM port 5985.
Example:

```
Azure portal->Network security group->new->name and description for the NSG->Create new-> Inbound security rules->New rule->Select the TCP protocol->Service as WinRM-> In the Destination port ranges box, type 5985- specific IP address or subnet that you want to allow access to WinRM port 5985-> Apply
```

[image]

Second scenario:
If you want to [specify which IP-addresses the WinRM service will listen on](https://support.vscope.net/how-to-enable-winrm-on-windows-servers-clients#:%7E:text=WinRM%20uses%20ports%205985%20%28HTTP,node%20and%20choose%20New%20Rule.) from OS level i.e. on the server this is going to be migrated, then follow the steps mentioned [here](https://support.vscope.net/how-to-enable-winrm-on-windows-servers-clients#:%7E:text=WinRM%20uses%20ports%205985%20%28HTTP,node%20and%20choose%20New%20Rule.)

If you are trying to find the IP address of the Azure Migrate Appliance, that should be available under the list of VMs hosted under your hyper-V / VMware as below-
[image]

If it is physical server then it should be the IP address of the server the Azure Migrate appliance software is installed on.